# Remove the console log lines of INFO in cucumber-reporting

Tags: cucumber

When I run my tests using maven, I get the following lines as an output for every feature file

```
May 31, 2020 4:46:58 PM net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser parseJsonFiles
INFO: File 'C:\EclipseWorkspace\EC\target\cucumber-html-reports\EC.E2E_WNG.DateFilter_ByDC.json' contains 1 features
```

Is there a way to hide this from the console log? This happens for every feature file that is run or skipped and when we have hundreds of them, it is creating noise.

Having a look at the source code here:

```
https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/blob/master/src/main/java/net/masterthought/cucumber/ReportParser.java
```

Is there a way to comment this line in the ReportParser.java file or do anything similar to resolve the issue I am facing?

```
LOG.log(Level.INFO, String.format("File '%s' contains %d features", jsonFile, features.length));
```